# how to access data from mysql

Tags: mysql

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id="{HOW TO ACCESS ID FROM THE SELECT ABVOE?}"
COMMIT;
```

What I'm looking for is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think What you need is this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  DELETE FROM tab1 
  where id = (SELECT id FROM tab1 WHERE /*your condition here*/);
COMMIT;
```

**Edit:** Based on the OP' comment below, There is no way to tell which row was the last deleted one, but you can create a [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to do that for you, See [This tutorial.](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-delete.shtml)

Comment: I need to return the ID to teh php script as well.

Comment: There is no way to tell what is the last row has been deleted, but you can use trigger to do that see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: lol if I wouldn't want to get the ID and pass it to the php I would simply use DELETER FROM tab1 WHERE STATEMENT

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL code you need, in order to achieve what you've asked for.

```
START TRANSACTION;
   DELETE 
   FROM tab1
   WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id
     FROM tab1 
     WHERE 1=1
     LIMIT 1
   )
COMMIT;
```

In order to pass the results back to PHP, you have to use [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

Comment: I need to return the ID to teh php script as well.

Answer (score 0):

from your query:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
    DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id="{HOW TO ACCESS ID FROM THE SELECT ABVOE?}"
COMMIT;
```

i believed that you want to delete the first record on the table.
you can get a hint from this example:

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
    UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
    SELECT @A as UpdateID;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I need to return the ID to teh php script as well.