# innodb transaction and user-defined variables?

Tags: mysql

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id="{HOW TO ACCESS ID FROM THE SELECT ABVOE?}"
COMMIT;
```

I would like to get the id of the selected row, delete it and return the id to the PHP `(mysql_fetch_array());`

Comment: please edit your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870543/how-to-access-data-from-mysql

Comment: What's the use of your WHERE condition in the SELECT statement?

Comment: you can do it with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM tab1 LIMIT 1);
```

Your `WHERE` is pointless. I don't know the purpose of the query but this how you'd do it.
Alternatively, you can save the result of the first query in a session variable.

```
SET @result = (SELECT id FROM  tab1 LIMIT 1);

DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE id = @result;
```

Comment: how can I retrieve the @result, so that I can use mysql_fetch_*?

Comment: By creating and using a stored procedure. Google about MySQL's stored procedures and functions.